# Commercial usage of wit.ai

Tags: wit.ai

**Some one from wit.ai team please answer this**

We are planning to use wit.ai for commercial purpose. Is there any usage policy? Please provide some guidelines of Dos and Don'ts. Also, will this service be free in future also or are you planning on launching an enterprise version?

Mainly, what about the API hit rate, in our use case the number of API calls would be around 100K calls per day?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try reading FAQ, all the info there. But I write your questions and answer here. Source : https://wit.ai/faq

What is your pricing?
Wit is free, including for commercial use. So both private and public Wit apps are free and are governed by our terms.

Is there any rate limit?
We don't have a strict rate limit. Use common sense and please contact us if you plan to hit our API quite heavily (sustained rate of 1 request/sec).

Comment: @raviteja is it not true? why you unchecked the answer?

Comment: Wit.ai crew here, I confirm Wit.ai is free an unlimited as long as it's "fair use" (roughly meaning that queries have to originate from humans).

Comment: @Blacksad The main question that seems to be nowhere answered is: how long it is going to be free. Is the wit.ai open-source?

Answer (score 0):

In current wit.ai FAQ page, there is some information on rate limiting.

> Is there any rate limit?
>   We have a rate limit of 200 samples posted per minute. Please contact us if your app requires exceeding this limit.

You can learn more about it here: https://wit.ai/faq

Answer (score 0):

As of today (dic '21), service is still [free](https://wit.ai/faq):

> What is your pricing?
> Wit is free, including for commercial use. So both private and public Wit apps are free and governed by our terms.

of course under its own [terms](https://wit.ai/terms) which take into account a number of topics, e.g. like "intellectual property" and "prohibitions".

There still is a [rate limit](https://wit.ai/faq):

> Is there any rate limit?
> To support all our community, we do impose rate limiting. Please refer to our latest HTTP API documentation for the current rate limiting per endpoint.

that in case of [speech-to-text requests](https://wit.ai/docs/http/20210928/#post__speech_link) amounts to:

> a rate limit of 240 requests per minute per user, and 60 requests per minute per app.